# Quick methods Javascript/Jquery/etc to retrieve all aspnet:textbox (input) contained in a form, excluding other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, counter

I created a '**test Label**' or alert to see values of variables (some way to know values of variables like in Matlab?)

How can I change so i can retrieve the correct number of elements as required (and not value '0' or 'all elements' or 'errors')?

Code is this:

```
var lenform = document.getElementById("ActionInMoveID").length;
var selform = document.getElementById("ActionInMoveID");

var count = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < lenform; k++) 
    {
    if (selform.elements[k].tagName == "input")
    count++;
    }
alert(count);
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript:

```
var count = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
```

In jQuery:

```
var count = $('#form').find(':input').length;
```

To retrieve each one of inputs in JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // do what you wan to do with inputs[i] element
}
```

in jQuery:

```
$('#form').find(':input').each(function(){
    // do what you wan to do with $(this) element
})
```

Comment: ok, but then i would like to isolate them, so as i can retrieve informations from any of them

Comment: and sorry if i want textboxes inside a specified form only?
cause i have a lot of textboxes outside that tag and i need to separate. Also the tag in aspnet have different name in server or client side...
thank you!

Comment: Pay attention on the $('#form') selector in jQuery. Here the work 'form' should be your specific form id, for example 'form1' so you will receive the elements inside this form